# Get whole line that includes something

Tags: php, php-5.6

Basically I have a text file that has multiple lines and if a line includes what I am looking for I want that whole line.

For example, here is what might be in the text file:

```
Apple1:Banana1:Pear1
Apple2:Banana2:Pear2
Apple3:Banana3:Pear3
```

If there is a line with Apple2 in it for example, how can I use php to get that whole line `(Apple2:Banana2:Pear2)`  and have it stored in a variable?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach I would take.

```
$string = 'Apple1:Banana1:Pear1
Apple2:Banana2:Pear2
Apple3:Banana3:Pear3
Apple22:Apple24:Pear2
Apple2s:Apple24:Pear2';
$target = 'Apple2';
preg_match_all('~^(.*\b' . preg_quote($target) . '\b.*)$~m', $string, $output);
print_r($output[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Apple2:Banana2:Pear2
)
```

The `m` modifier here is important, php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php. As is the `preg_quote` (unless you are careful about your search term), http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php.

**Update:**

To require the line start with the targeted term use this updated regex.

```
preg_match_all('~^(' . preg_quote($target) . '\b.*)$~m', $string, $output);
```

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/uY0jC6/1

Comment: Your answer seems to be working for me but do you think you can fix it so that it only shows results that start with Apple2 please?

Comment: Updated regex to match the start.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = 'text.txt';
$lines = file($file);
$result = null;
foreach($lines as $line){
    if(preg_match('#banana#', $line)){
        $result = $line;
    }
}

if ($result == null) {
    echo 'Not found';
} else {
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Yann's edit adds a check to prevent it trying to echo an empty result :)

Answer (score 0):

I like `preg_grep()`.  This finds `Apple2` anywhere:

```
$lines = file('path/to/file.txt');
$result = preg_grep('/Apple2/', $lines);
```

This finds only entries starting with `Apple2`:

```
$result = preg_grep('/^Apple2/', $lines);
```

There are many possibilities with the pattern depending upon what you want.  Read here http://www.regular-expressions.info